# Credit Card Validation using mod-10 Algorithm in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, webforms

I'm trying to apply the mod-10 luhn's credit card validation techquine on a custom validation control in asp.net. I created a textbox to enter the credit card numbers, then used the controltovalidate property to link the textbox to the validation control. I thought i had everything coded in correctly, but when i run the debugger, nothing is happening. I tried to use breakpoints, and it looks like the debugger isn't even reaching the code that works to validate anything. I'm confused. Am I missing something like a postback or a event handler? Here is the code for the aspx.net and the C#.

```
//C# Code:
protected void CustomValidator1_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    args.IsValid = ValidateCreditCard(args.Value);
}

private bool ValidateCreditCard(string cardNumber)
{
    cardNumber = txtCreditCard.Text;
    int digitSum = 0;
    string digits = "";
    string reversedCardNumber = "";

    //removes spaces and reverse string 
    cardNumber = cardNumber.Replace(" ", null);
    for (int i = cardNumber.Length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        reversedCardNumber += cardNumber[i];
    }

    //double the digits in even-numbered positions
    for (int i = 0; i < reversedCardNumber.Length; i++)
    {
        if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0)
        {
            digits += Convert.ToInt32(reversedCardNumber.Substring(i, 1)) *2;
        }
        else
        {
            digits += reversedCardNumber.Substring(i, 1);
        }
    }

    //add the digits
    for (int i = 0; i < digits.Length; i++)
    {
        digitSum += Convert.ToInt32(digits.Substring(i, 1));
    }

    //Check that the sum is divisible by 10
    if ((digitSum % 10) == 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Here is the ASPX.NET code I'm using for the controls I have set up:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCreditCard" runat="server" Width="216px"
    AutoPostBack="True">1111 1111 1111 1111</asp:TextBox>

<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1"
    ControlToValidate="txtCreditCard" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="Credit Card Not Vaild"
    OnServerValidate="CustomValidator1_ServerValidate">
</asp:CustomValidator>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click"  
Text="Process" />
```

Update: This code has been fixed to work now. Hopefully this will help anyone else who runs across this problem.

Comment: The validator should run when you click an `<asp:Button>`. It won't run automatically on AutoPostBack.

Comment: That means I would have to call the CustomValidator1_ServerValidate Method into a button, right? How would i properly pass the arguments for that if i had to do that?

Comment: You were right michael once, I put the ValidateCreditCard() method into a button, and once I ran the debugger it properly called the method. Still....When I try a valid credit Card, It not flagging it as true. Kinda confused about that.

Comment: I finally got it to work based on some of your help michael thanks. Once i followed your advice to use an asp button to call the validatecreditcard() method, I realized the reason why it wasn't properly validating credit card numbers was because I forgot to mulitple the reversedcardnumbers.substring by 2. So when the digitSum was being checked to see if it was divisible by 10 to flag true or false, it wasn't properly doing that. I revised the code up top if anyone stumbles across it, and needs  help like i did. Thank you.